# Which school is right for me?

Tags: personal-practice, sects

Apologies in advance if this is something you see often.

I've been interested in Buddhism for a year now. I've read what I could find and do intend to read more. It seems Buddhism is like a tree, with each branch representing a different sect, and each leaf representing a different school. I'm not making sense I bet. Anyway, since I'm 100% new to Buddhism and realise I don't know up from down regarding it, maybe someone here can set me straight.

I'm asking which sect/branch would be right for me. I can't find much information on the differences, as the articles I've read emphasize the sense of community across all sects and schools. Which is fine! I'm not here to create a schism. Just here to start on the path that is best suited for me. I'm big on self-improvement, so I guess a sect with that emphasis would be best for me. More information if requested.

Thanks again.

Comment: previous attempts to answer similar questions were not very successful - the first question in this vein goes back to this site's first month (http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/57/what-are-the-main-differences-between-the-theravada-mahayana-and-vajrayana-bran). Yours makes it even more difficult by adding your personal character as factor we know nothing about.